# Will WebSocket achieve what I'm trying to do?

Tags: java, websocket

I'm creating a simple java application made in swing that communicates with a database. Multiple people will be using the application at the same time. As they are able to change things at the same time, if someone for example, adds a new user, and a different person is on that same page, I want the person who did not make the change to be notified that changes were made to the database since they last loaded it.

My lecturer in college advised me that WebSockets would be the way to go to achieve this, however after some reading about WebSockets in Java, it seems it is based to work with web browsers instead of between Java applications.

Can using WebSockets achieve what I am trying? Or, if not, what would be a way to achieve this?

Comment: Thanks for the downvote, now can you please explain why so I can improve this question.

Comment: Yes you can achieve this, you have to write a custom server to facilitate the requirements. In your case pushing database changes to the client (server push). FYI I am not the down-voter.
By writing a java client and a server you can communicate with each other.

Comment: The downvote is likely because this is a very general question without very many specifics and broad architectural questions are generally off-topic here on stackoverflow because there is no specific answer, just lots of opinions.  Yes, a webSocket can be used to send notifications from a server to a client or between two clients.  Since your app is Java where you can use pretty much any technology you want, so could lots of other types of TCP connections.

Comment: General? I'm asking if what I'm asking is achievable with the API in question.. regardless, there is enough information in both comments to satisfy my question. I would accept either as an answer. The first has guided me in the right direction and I have discovered a few potential solutions since then. I was unsure because all tutorials seem to use HTML in them and I was wondering if WebSockets were a HTML specific thing because, you know.. software can be like that sometimes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer is **Yes you can achieve what you needed**

WebSocket is a communication protocol(@see [RFC 6455](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455)) & it is **not a must** to use a Web browser.

You can achieve what you want to do with your app, it is just a matter of writing a custom WebSocket server to facilitate your requirements in your case sending database changes to the other clients(Which is called Server push)

There are several java libraries to get the work done,

- [netty WebSocket](https://github.com/netty/netty/tree/4.1/codec-http/src/main/java/io/netty/handler/codec/http/websocketx) (My favorite)
- jWebsocket
- Atmosphere
- Webbit

Netty WebSocket is a good one to start with and you can find examples in [its project](https://github.com/netty/netty/tree/4.1/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/http/websocketx) to write a custom client and a server